# Where can I find the default template for the Expander control?

Tags: winui-3

I need to modify the template of the Expander control (move the chevron icon to the left), but I could not find it.

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.expander?view=winui-3.0#control-style-and-template

> The default style, template, and resources that define the look of the control are included in the generic.xaml file. For design purposes, generic.xaml is available in the (Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\ \Generic folder from a Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) installation. Styles and resources from different versions of the SDK might have different values.

The generic.xaml in that location does not have the default template of the Expander control.

I also looked in the generic.xaml from `%Users%\myuser\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.0.0\lib\net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0\Microsoft.WinUI\Themes\generic.xaml`

So confusing. Back in the old WPF\UWP days I could just do Edit Template in Visual Studio, but with WinUI, that's not available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the resource that you are looking for? https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev/Expander

This is from the book "Modernizing Your Windows Applications with the Windows App SDK and WinUI" by Matteo Pagini and Marc Plogas ([Link to publisher](https://www.packtpub.com/product/programming/9781803235660)):

> If you want to customize the template of one of the most recent
> controls that were added since WinUI 2.x, you will find the template
> in the GitHub repository of the project
> https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/

Comment: it's been a long time since I needed that, but since you answered... :)